# Django Rest Framework not retrieving data from my database

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm creating an API endpoint to retrieve data from a Mongo database, in order to use it on my frontend.

On my project, i'm using two DBs: a sqlite db and the Mongo DB.

In the Mongo database, there is a collection called `tst` with some data in it. I created the endpoint, but after opening the api on my browser, i see no json data retrieved from the collection, as if it's not looking in the right place.

Can someone help me find what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my model:

```
class tst(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticker = models.FloatField()

    def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
        super(tst, self).save(*args, using='dbtwo', **kwargs)
```

Here is my view:

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.using('dbtwo').all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class tstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = tst
        fields = ('id', 'ticker', )
```

And the url:

```
path('tst/', views.tstList.as_view()),
```

Comment: As a first step, you could override `get_queryset` in your `tstList`, print the queryset and see if it includes any data: `print(self.queryset)`

Comment: This may sound stupid, but have you checked that there actually are any `tst` objects in your `dbtwo` database?

Comment: I'm correcting the errors, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I setup 2 databases like yourself, changed your code a bit, added 2 `tst` objects to the database and retrieved JSON data of these 2 `tst` objects in my API call.

I slightly changed the `models.py` by adding `primary_key=True` to the `id` field.

```
# models.py

class tst(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    ticker = models.FloatField()

    def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
        super(tst, self).save(*args, using='dbtwo', **kwargs)
```

I changed the `views.py` so it uses a [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) like this:

```
# views.py

from rest_framework import viewsets

class tstList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = tst.objects.using('dbtwo').all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
```

I did not change anything to the serializer so mine looks like this:

```
# serializers.py

class tstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = tst
        fields = ('id', 'ticker',)
```

Finally in the `urls.py` I used a [`DefaultRouter()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) and registered the `tstList` view as an endpoint like this:

```
# urls.py

from rest_framework import routers
# imported tstList view here

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'test', views.tstList, base_name='test')
```

Then I ran the following commands in my terminal:

- `manage.py makemigrations`
- `manage.py migrate --database dbtwo`
- `manage.py runserver`

I then created two `tst` objects with random float values for their `ticker` fields.

#### The GET request and results

When I now make a GET request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/` I get the following results:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "ticker": 1.2
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "ticker": 1.7
    }
]
```